# Two seemingly simple questions in group theory and complex analysis

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis

1. If I have $\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$, doesnt this limit not exist? $\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2} = \lim \limits_{(a,b) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{a^2-b^2-2abi}{a^2-b^2+2abi}  $. If you take $a=0$ first, then the limit evaluates to $\frac{-b^2}{-b^2} = 1$. if you take $a=b$, then the limit is $-1$. Thus the limit depends on the direction we take so it must not exist at zero? Yet, wolfram alpha says its 1.
2. What are the generators of the cyclic group of  $Z_{17}$ under multiplication? Are there any?

Comment: 3 is a generator of $Z_{17}$. The set of all generators is the set of odd powers of 3 in $Z_{17}$, namely, the numbers = 3, 10, 5, 11, 14, 7, 12, 6.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this site, users are encouraged *not* to put multiple questions inside one posting, so that people can identify duplicate questions easily and readers who are only interested in one of your questions can follow the discussion without difficulty. Next time, please separate your questions into different postings.

Answer (score 1):

Hints :

1. Consider $z=\rho\,e^{i\phi}$ and compute $\dfrac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$ (your method and conclusion are right too).
2. Observe that the [Euler totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi(n)$ function gives the number of positive integers smaller than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ or... count them (the multiplicative group has $\,n=\cdots$ elements).
3. If $n$ is a power of $2$ then the generators are all the non-powers of $2\pmod{17}$.